# Can a proposition contain variables?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I understand that proposition logic can be expressed as `3=3`, and predicate logic can be expressed as `x+3=5`. However I am unsure if proposition logic can contain a statement such as `x=3`? A simple yes or no answer is all I am searching for. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You should study the propositional and predicate logic a bit more (especially the syntax of these languages). Propositional logic connects "propositions" (statements that can be associated to a truth value *true* or *false*). For instance $p$ : "The cat in on the mat". We don't have equality or numbers. Predicate logic connects predicates/properties and allows quantification over objects/individuals. So the answer is no.

Comment: @Boris Eng Thanks, I am still currently studying this subject but ran into this question whilst studying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are definitely not part of propositional logic.

I *suppose* we could define our propositional logic language to allow expressions like $Siblings(a,b)$ for readability sake to express atomic statements (instead of your typical $P$'s and $Q$'s) *as long as* you do *not* *analyze* that statement as consisting of those parts. That is, in propositional logic, atomic statements are exactly that: *atomic* statements without any further composition or structure. Indeed, if you were to use $3=3$ in such a language for propositional logic, it would be considered just like any other atomic statement, i.e. something that could be either true or false. But in predicate logic, the $=$ is a logical symbol, and there $3=3$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

Siblings(a, b), meaning a and b are siblings, is a declarative statement whose truth value is undetermined. Therefore, is not a proposition. 2 > 3 is a proposition.